# Machines components?

Tags: structural-analysis

When analyzing machines, how to tell if a point that was attached to another part will have only an $x$ or $y$ component or both?

[image: here]

why wouldn't point $B$, $C$ and $A$ have an $x$ component?

Comment: they all have 3 dimensions of position, but what are you referring to ? vector of connecting force if it is radial or cartesian or what?  I guess take the derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a reaction has both x and y components is going to depend on the geometry of the machine components and the orientation of the applied load. In the machine example you provided it appears all the components are pin connected, which means they *potentially* have both x and y components. With experience, you may be able to determine by inspection if one of these components is zero. In the meantime, I find it easiest to simply assume nonzero components for both the x and y direction. Solving the equations of equilibrium will generally reveal if one of the components is zero.

As an example, looking at the machine you provided, we can determine by inspection that there is no x reaction at A or D because for link A-D to be in equilibrium there cannot be forces in the x direction. F_Ax and F_Dx would need to be equal and opposite to satisfy horizontal force equilibrium and that would produce a moment on the link (not allowed by equilibrium).

With no x reaction at D, then for equilibrium of the bottom jaw, there can be no x reaction at E.

For the lower handle, with no x reaction at E and only vertical load applied, there can be no x reaction at C.

For the upper handle, with no x reaction at C and only vertical load applied, there can be no x reaction at B.

In equilibrium we trust.

---

The image below shows an example of y-equilibrium. (I didn’t actually work out magnitudes and directions...just the principle of how forces might flow.)

[image: Assuming y-reactions only]

Looking just at the upper handle it’s possible to imagine that component remaining in equilibrium if we assumed x reactions at B and C (equal and opposite). However, when we follow those reactions throughout the machine it leads to a link AD that is not in equilibrium.

[image: Assuming x-reactions]

So, we have to assume no x reactions at link AD. When we follow that assumption throughout the machine we end up with no x reactions at all.

Comment: actually I think you can argue there is no "x" force in any of the pins in this example.

Comment: I believe you are correct, I updated my answer to reflect the logic for all the subsequent pins.

Comment: I can see it a bit better, but can we not argue for the above example that both B and C have an x component, but are opposite and hence cancel each other?

Comment: I can see what you’re thinking. But the whole machine has to be in equilibrium. An x reaction at B would transfer into the top jaw and would have to be balanced by an x reaction at A (since no x reaction possible at the ball the pliers are gripping). And as discussed above, there can’t be an x reaction at A if the link AD is to be in equilibrium.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this clears a lot of things, you are the best.